execute function on button press
I am trying to execute a function on button press. I tried different method
found on tutorials but with no avail, it gives the following error
`Thirdwindow.getSingleRows() takes 0 positional arguments but
1 was given
the problem is in this line:on_press: root.getSingleRows()
I tried self.getSingleRows() it gives this error
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'getSingleRows'
the problem is not with the function that is uses the database
i removed it and used the simple print() method, but it is the same error
import kivy


         from kivy.config import Config
         Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
         Config.set('graphics', 'height', '500')
         from kivy.app import App
         from kivy.lang import Builder
         from kivy.uix.label import Label
         from kivy.uix.image import Image
         import sqlite3
         from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen



    
        


        class Firstwindow(Screen):
             pass
        class Secondwindow(Screen):
            pass
        class Thirdwindow(Screen):
             def getSingleRows():
        
            connection = sqlite3.connect('book.db')
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            print("Connected to database")

            sqlite_select_query = """SELECT question FROM advanced"""
            cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
            print("Fetching single row")
            record = cursor.fetchone()
            print(record)

            print("Fetching next row")
            record = cursor.fetchone()
            print(record)

            cursor.close()

    

       class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
           def screen_manager_method(self):
           pass
       class CrashCourse(App):
       def build(self):
        Builder.load_file("crashcourse.kv")
        return WindowManager()
       if __name__ == '__main__':
           CrashCourse().run()`












`    crashcourse.kv



<WindowManager>:
     Firstwindow:
     Secondwindow:
     Thirdwindow:
<Firstwindow>:
     ``canvas:
      Rectangle:
           source:"down.jpg"
           size: self.size
 name: "home_screen"
 id: home_screen
 Button:
      id: b1
      text: 'Beginner'
      color:"purple"
      pos:200,300
      size_hint:(0.2,0.1)
      on_release:
           app.root.current="game_screen"
 Button:
      id: b2
      text:" Inermediate"
      color:"purple"
      pos:200,230
      size_hint:(0.2,0.1)
 Button:
      id: b3
      text:"Advanced"
      color:"purple"
      pos:200,160
      size_hint:(0.2,0.1)
      on_release:
           app.root.current="menu_screen"

 <Secondwindow>:
 name: "menu_screen"
 id: menu_screen
 Label:
      text:"this is screen two"
<Thirdwindow>:
 name: "game_screen"
 id: game_screen
 GridLayout
      
      cols:2
      Label:
           text:"first checkbox"
      CheckBox:
           group:"mygroup"
           on_active: root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,"first checkbox")
      Label:
           text:"second  radio button"
      CheckBox:
           group:"mygroup"
           on_active: root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,"second radio button")
      Label:
           text:"third radio button"
      CheckBox:
           group:"mygroup"
           on_active: root.checkbox_click(self,self.active,"third radio button")
      Button:
           
           text:"Move Next"
           on_press: root.getSingleRows()




Change def getSingleRows(): to def getSingleRows(self):

it gives the following error: 'Button' object has no attribute 'getSingleRows'

Place your getSingleRows(self): inside your App class and change the button press to app.getSingleRows()
